# How to get focused child of ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a ListView in which i add row items dynamically. Each row has a no of childs. Now i am setting on click listeners on these childs, and in them it asks me to keep these child items final, it works fine with them and it is ok to do this as i am creating a class in each on click listener.

Here isFree is a final checkBox.

```
isFree.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (isFree.isChecked()){...}
    }
});
```

But i dont feel it as a good programming practice, i want to use some function which should detect which child was clicked and then i should be able to access its row using getParent and then its sibling items using getChildAt(index)
So, i used this:

```
isFree.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        CheckBox tv=(CheckBox) getCurrentFocus();
        TableRow row = (TableRow)tv.getParent();
        TextView tv1=(TextView) row.getChildAt(5);
        if (tv.isChecked()){...}
    }
});
```

But when i use it, on focussed item actualy returns the listview, but i want focused item in the row.

Answer (score 0):

you can get which child of listview was clicked with onItemClickListener, but if you want to do some action on a row which has some checkbox or some other clickable view and you want to perform some action on those click then i think you have to use click listeners on those views itself.

but if you want to get listitem row at click of those individual views, you can use setTag method of view class to store the index and then getting the row item from that index on your click listeners.

```
public view getView(int position, View convertView, ..) {
  ....
  ....
  ....
  // your code
  convertView.setTag(position);
  return convertView;
}

isFree.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (arg0.isChecked()){
            int index = arg0.getTag();
            View v = listview.getItemAtPosition(index);
            // or  get the adapter get data list from it and then index it.

        }
    }
});
```

NOTE that: I havent used final free inside oncheckedchange method.

Answer (score 0):

On the `setOnCheckedChangeListener` method, the first parameter is a `CompoundButton` that is a super-class of `CheckBox`. So, actually, arg0 is your checkbox. Use it to retrieve the parent list item and make your stuff.

```
isFree.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TableRow row = (TableRow)arg0.getParent();
        TextView tv1=(TextView) row.getChildAt(5);
        if (arg0.isChecked()){...}
    }
});
```